# How to get the UUID for a dotCloud application?

Tags: uuid, dotcloud

some PaaS providers have an **APPLICATION_UUID** env variable which is obviously unique (at least across their platform).

Is there anything similar for DotCloud? I'm not finding anything like that in *environment.json*

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a UUID, but if you are trying to tell different instances from each other, you can use the dotcloud configuration values from the environment.json file:

DOTCLOUD_PROJECT : which is the name you have given the dotcloud application
DOTCLOUD_SERVICE_NAME : which is the name you give each service (typically www, or data, etc)
DOTCLOUD_SERVICE_ID : the instance number of a particular instance, starting at 0

If you concatenate the 3, it would create a unique identifier across all of your dotcloud applications, services, and instances.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything like that exposed externally. What do you need it for, maybe I can suggest an alternative?

Comment: Hi Ken, sorry for the late reply but i missed the notification. I have a script (called registration agent) which will scan locally installed packages into your application and submit it to http://www.dif.io. This uses a unique value to identify the application so that when you submit the info again it will update it, instead of creating a new entry.  I did a workaround by asking the user to provide some unique value as a config variable before using the script. What do you suggest?